# Finding average from input array with Javascript - not calculating correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, moving-average

I am trying to calculate the average of 3 values (each numbered from 1-10) that are selected by the user and then pass the results to an text input (for display as a graph).

It should be updating the new average every time one of the values is changed, but the averaging is not working correctly at all. I think that the loop is not resetting the values every time it runs- it's adding up the sum each time it runs, but not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
var sliders = $("#health1,#health2,#health3");

var elmt = [];

$(sliders).each(function () {
    elmt.push($(this).attr('value'));

    $("#health1,#health2,#health3").change(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        averageRisk();
    });
});

function averageRisk() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(elmt[i], 10);
    }

    var avg = sum / elmt.length;
    document.getElementById('healthLevel').value = +avg;

    elmt.push($(sliders).attr('value'));
    $('#healthLevel').val(avg).trigger('change');

    console.log("Sum: " + sum);
    console.log("Average: " + avg);
}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelmix/783cfmnv/

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `elmt.pop()` or `elmt=[];` somewhere? Otherwise, you're just adding to the array all the time.

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/783cfmnv/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but seems like a lot of extra work going. Main issue was you were building array of initial values and not getting the values each time they changed. That first `.each` got all the slider values and added them to `elmt` and continued to push new values on to after every change instead of just getting the current values every time. Did you want to accumulate all values over time?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/783cfmnv/6/

```
$("#health1,#health2,#health3").on('change', function () {
    averageRisk();
});

function averageRisk() {
    var sum = 0;
    var elmt = $("#health1,#health2,#health3");
    for (var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(elmt[i].value, 10); //don't forget to add the base
    }

    var avg = sum / elmt.length;
    document.getElementById('healthLevel').value = +avg;

    $('#healthLevel').val(avg).trigger('change');
    console.log("Sum: " + sum);
    console.log("Average: " + avg);
}
```

And as pointed out if you want to ignore updating things when the sum is NaN you can do this:

```
function averageRisk() {
    var sum = 0;
    var elmt = $("#health1,#health2,#health3");
    for (var i = 0; i < elmt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(elmt[i].value, 10); //don't forget to add the base
    }

    if (isNaN(sum)) {
        return false;
    }

    var avg = sum / elmt.length;
    document.getElementById('healthLevel').value = +avg;

    $('#healthLevel').val(avg).trigger('change');
    console.log("Sum: " + sum);
    console.log("Average: " + avg);
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  It may be desirable for it to ignore empty elements (or act as though they are 0 ?) because right now an empty element will fill "NaN"

Comment: Very true! Updated answer.

Comment: Yes I agree this is a great solution. it works just as I wanted it to. In my case it's not possible to have a value of 0, but I can see the usefulness of having something in place for this.

Comment: Well the update doesn't take into account 0 but it will not update the average if its not a number. This solution can easily be extended to handle many situations I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you fill the `elmt` array at page loading.

When user changes the values, you do not refresh the `elmt` array. So the array used to compute the average is always the same, empty.

You have to recover the input values each time they are modified.

```
function averageRisk() {
    var sum = 0;

    // Re make the loop for getting all inputs values
    $(sliders).each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        sum += value;
    });

    var avg = sum/$(sliders).length;

    $('#healthLevel').val(avg);
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/783cfmnv/7/

PS : You can use the css class `healthInput` to select your inputs. If you add later other fields, you will not have to add the new input id to your jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

I did this work, check it .

http://jsfiddle.net/783cfmnv/10/

```
$("#health1,#health2,#health3").change(function() {
             var val1 = +slider1.val();
                var val2 = +slider2.val();
                var val3 = +slider3.val();
             var avg = (val1 + val2 + val3) /3;  
             $("#healthLevel").val(avg);                  
            });
```